# Backbone dynamically set collection view el after click on dom element

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

the project is calendar where model is 1 day and collection contain all days from the month. The View is the same. So when i render my collection i have calendar on the screen. Now what i need, is to be able to set todo list in selected day. So i need another model,view and collection. My idea is that tasks from one day will be this day collection but - and there we go to the problem : how to set this new collection view "el" to element of the clicked day and its id. Each day has got the same class and unique id equal to  date -  like "2013.02.08"  I am not sure is it possible or maybe my approach is wrong and i should do this in another way. Edit - ok lets clarify :

I know that there in no collection of collections so how to do it ?
I have calendar on the screen - imagine 31 square divs.
I want a todo list in each of them - so it will be :

```
model of task
view of task {li element}
view of tasks {ul element}
collection of tasks {model:model}
```

in each of the squares. How to store all those collections ?

Comment: Tip: it would be helpful to post the a relevant portion of the code you have so far. Your problem is a bit hard to understand from the description alone.

Comment: i just realized my approach is completly wrong - sorry for bothering you